# Npm start "The development server returned response error code:500"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-layout, expo, npm-start

Hello stackoverflow family,
I hope you are all will be fine. I am a beginner in react native. When I am trying to create a new project an error window will open " the development server returned response error code: 500 " please help me to fix this problem.

[image]